# how to check file exist in php using only extension like (*.pdf)

Tags: php, file-exists

```
$filename = '/www/test1/*.pdf';
    if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
        echo "The file $filename exists";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    }
```

I used above code but it checks for *.pdf file but not for all files belongs to .pdf extension

Comment: What result do you expect here? You want to test whether *any* file with a PDF extension exists in that directory?

Comment: Thanks for your support. yes, i was searching for any file available with a PDF extension in the directory and as per Mr.Mark Baker's post, i got the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$filename = '/www/test1/*.pdf';
if (count(glob($filename)) > 0) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```